# What could the consequences be for bad initialisation of pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, mmu

**THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN CLOSED BECAUSE IT DIDN'T SEEM A REAL QUESTION TO SOME PEOPLE** I have updated the question body since then and may be it is a bit better now. However, I expect you all to suggest how I can improve this question as it is my job and research into this area.

RAII (Resource Allocation is Initialisation) theory dictates that if I borrow memory from MMU, I need to return it back (new and delete). However, I was wondering the consequesnces would be if I was doing bad initialisation practices in C++.

What if I do the following:

```
double* pp1 = 0;
double* pp2 = 0;
```

And then use pp1 and pp2 somewhere I need to? Is that the wrong way of initialising a pointer according to standard programming practice? Or is it initialisation at all. Is initialisation entirely depended on `new` operator?

And how much use of pointers should there be in a design that is:

1) Real-Time
2) Safety Critical
3) Mission Critical

Also, I am finding strange outcomes when running same C/C++ application in 32-bit and 64-bit machines. How badly will my machine become slow/underperform if I was messing around with pointers. Because, my machine is getting slow due to using too many pointers in my design. For some "obvious" Non-Disclosure Agreement, I cannot put my code here. I am so sorry about that. And for clarification, I am deleting all the pointers used in every method just before I return my results i.e. my memory management is well-balanced and efficient enough not to cause stack overflow issues.

I know these questions may be too open-ended but I am also investigating (Google, MISRA C++, British Computer Society, and IEEE) to find out a detailed answer. My idea is to actually research and develop a way to program in C++ without involving pointers a lot.

I know that an obvious answer is,"You program in C++ so that you can use pointers and stop abusing MMU of your PC". But if anyone has any different thoughts I would like to hear about it.

Comment: By the way, use `nullptr` instead of `0` now.

Comment: I would vote you down for not performing any basic research. All this should be covered quite early in your book.

Comment: @LaurynasBiveinis The question was quite obvious - The correct use of pointers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I politely asked readers not to vote anything for it. If you don't want to contribute, please don't and leave a comment that it is a trivial post and should be Googled more! Show some professional courtesy!

Comment: @jjabraham: Just asking people to alter the rules and policies of this website does not make it so. _You_ show some professional courtesy and perform even a morsel of basic research before asking me to devote my professional time to you for free!

Comment: "The correct use of pointers" is not a question, and "how do I use pointers correctly?" is too vague for this Q&A website.

Answer (score 6):

> Which would be the most appropriate practice of using pointers?

In this case, the answer would be **not to use them at all**. What's wrong with just

```
double p1 = 1.1;
double p2 = 2.2;
```

#### If you must, wrap them in a smart pointer:

Guard against memory leaks using a smart pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<double> pp1;
```

#### If you must use raw pointers (doubtful), initialize to `nullptr`:

Prefer `nullptr` over `NULL` or `0`:

```
double* pp1 = nullptr;
double* pp2 = nullptr;
```

You can't dereference the pointer until you make it point to a valid location:

```
pp1 = new double(1.1);

*pp1; //VALID
*pp2; //UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR - pp2 is still nullptr
```